# initialize tinyMCE with default content

Tags: javascript, html, initialization, tinymce, default

I have a quick question about **tinyMCE**. I have a textarea, with `id="mainbuffer"`, and the function `tinyMCE.get(id).setContent(data)`.

ONLY works when it is called `onclick="function()"` from a link and does not work when I load the page. In my case, it is: `tinyMCE.get('mainbuffer').setContent(  localStorage.getItem('mainbuffer') );`

I've tried `tinyMCE.execCommand()`, but that doesn't work either.

I want the JavaScript function to initialize the textarea with data stored in localStorage, which I have checked, is working fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put script on page load, make sure you put your code in document.ready or after TinyMCE and your element has been loaded.

```
document.ready=function(){
   //debug document.getElementById('mainbuffer') return not undefined?
   tinyMCE.get('mainbuffer').setContent( localStorage.getItem('mainbuffer') );
}
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, I downloaded and installed firebug. It gives me the error: TypeError: tinyMCE.get("mainbuffer") is undefined. However, it should be defined. The script for the tinymce and the tinymce init is above the document.ready function. The textarea is in the body of the html.

Comment: <textarea class="mceEditor" id="mainbuffer" onchange="showLMC()"></textarea>

Comment: The exact code:
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.ready=function(){
    alert( document.getElementById('mainbuffer') ); //returns [object HTMLTextAreaElement]
    tinyMCE.get('mainbuffer').setContent( localStorage.getItem('mainbuffer') );
   }
</script>

Comment: Wow I think I found a better way. Instead of using any of that, I can just install the tinyautosave plugin that autosaves the content every set interval, and it handles localstorage. I'll try that. It took me a bit of rummaging through the message forum at tinymce.com/forum to find this plugin.