# initialize tinymce with content

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a page containing one tinymce4 editor instance. I want to initialize this editor with some content, programmatically. I know that I have to call: `tinymce.get('editor').setContent('my content');`

However I have trouble to do this when tinymce is getting initialized. This question has already been asked: [initialize tinyMCE with default content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083361/initialize-tinymce-with-default-content) but the answer that was given at that time is not working, at least for tinymce4.

Here is what I have tried:

1st attempt:

```
    tinymce.init({
      mode: "textareas",
      ...
      setup: function (editor) {
         ...
         editor.setContent('my content');
      }
   });
```

-> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

2nd attempt:

```
    tinymce.init({
      mode: "textareas",
      ...
    };
    tinymce.get('editor').setContent('my content');
```

-> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setContent' of null 
(however if I do this when the page containing the tinymce editor has already been loaded, it works).

3rd attempt (SO 12083361 answer):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    tinymce.get('editor').setContent('my content');
});
```

-> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setContent' of null

All this fails with `tinymce.activeeditor.setContent('my content');` as well.

Where should I place `tinymce.get('editor').setContent('my content');`in my code to have it working ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With version 4 you should do it like this:

```
tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('custom');
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqa13zz4/).

Comment: This is good... but lacking when there are multiple editors on a page that need to be individually targeted :-(

Comment: What if we have more then one RTE on page? Is there any other solution...

Comment: @DamienSawyer i'm getting this error `tinymce editor error cannot read property doc is undefined` can you suggest me. code `var body = tinymce activeEditor.dom.doc.body`

Answer (score 0):

I've used the init_instance_callback, which is fired when the editor is ready to setContent.

```js
var options = { ... };
options.init_instance_callback = function (editor) {
    editor.setContent(initialContent);
};
$("some-selector").tinymce(options);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `tinymce editor error cannot read property doc is undefined` can you suggest me. code `var body = tinymce activeEditor.dom.doc.body`