# tinymce editor is not displaying and getcontent returns false

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

This is the path of tinymce:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.js"></script>
```

My text area is :

```
    <textarea name="description" id="description" class="texarea" >
```

this is my TinyMCE init code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 tinymce.init({
 selector: "texarea",theme: "modern",width: 680,height: 300,
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor ResponsiveFilemanager"
   ],
   toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
   toolbar2: "| ResponsiveFilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
   image_advtab: true ,

 external_filemanager_path:"ResponsiveFilemanager/filemanager/",
 filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,

 });
</script>
```

The problem is the text area is not showing the editor and

```
tinyMCE.get('description').getContent()
```

return  error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContent' of null". Please help me to find the error in this code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [initialize tinymce with content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839614/initialize-tinymce-with-content)

Comment: check your browser console. i think `tinymce.js` path problem is there.Also did you added jQuery library before this `tinymce.js`? Also `<script></script>` is missing in your shown code

Comment: yes I did added the jquery library and script tag.

Comment: And @Alive to Die there is no error in my console.

Comment: It would help people if you made a JS Fiddle or Codepen that showed your running code so they could help you identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. It's `textarea`, not `texarea`. Also, the last comma shouldn't be there:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 tinymce.init({
 selector: "textarea",theme: "modern",width: 680,height: 300,
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor ResponsiveFilemanager"
   ],
   toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
   toolbar2: "| ResponsiveFilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
   image_advtab: true ,

 external_filemanager_path:"ResponsiveFilemanager/filemanager/",
 filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager"

 });
</script>
```

EDIT:

Also, you're missing the closing tag of the `textarea`:

```
<textarea name="description" id="description" class="texarea" ></textarea>
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have done the changes, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Please check my edit, you're also missing the closing textarea tag.