# TypeError when trying to set tinymce content

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I cannot set content of my tinymce instance. It seems like this method is poorly implemented, since it does not work at all. I've seen all these threads ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083361/initialize-tinymce-with-default-content),[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508001/how-to-set-tinymce-default-content),[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390743/how-do-i-set-content-in-tinymce-4-preferably-within-the-document-ready-bl)) and I tried this code:

```
//1. results in error message
tinymce.get("myid").setContent('<span>some</span> html'); 
//2. results in error message
tinymce.get("myid").setContent('<span>some</span> html', {format : 'raw'}); 

//3. simply has no effect
tinymce.init({
    ...
    init_instance_callback: "insert_contents",
});
function insert_contents(inst){
    inst.setContent('<strong>Some contents</strong>');  
}
```

I'm using the very last version of tinymce. Hope someone knows, why it may not work.

Comment: What is the error message?  Also, remove the quotes in your final attempt so it's `init_instance_callback: insert_contents`

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: n.dom is undefined`

Comment: @ Archer. You were right. The whole problem was in quotes. Now it all works